# When does Nearby(connections) use Wifi hotspot (and 1 more)?

Tags: android, google-nearby

So, I was doing some tests on my early build of app and these are the things I observed.(I used 85 MB video)

1. The discoverer automatically connects to advertiser's Wifi Direct. As a result the discoverer loses its internet connectivity.
2. Even when sending video file it relies on Wifi Direct instead of using Hotspot, which is much faster (especially due to 5 ghz channel support).

So, my question is when will Nearby detect the need of Hotspot and start using it instead of using Wifi Direct?

Also, Is there a way to stick to Bluetooth connection unless explicitly asked for faster (Wifi Direct) connection? It can be useful when chatting locally(does not need speed of Wifi direct).